# PHP: Updating double-quoted string inside a while loop

Tags: php

I'm expecting this to print from "Count 1" to "Count 9". But the $str variable is not updating inside the while loop. It just prints "Count 1" nine times. In my use-case it's not possible to initiate $str inside the while loop therefore I'm looking for a dynamic update of the $str var inside the while loop.

```
    $p   = 1;
    $str = "Count {$p}";
    while ( $p < 10 ) {
        $p++;
        echo  $str . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: _"In my use-case it's not possible to initiate $str inside the while loop"_ Please tell us more about your use case. If nothing else, how about doing a separate loop which initializes an array of strings, then use your `while()` loop to echo out those strings?

Comment: You could for example put a placeholder in $str, and then use `sprintf` to get that substituted with the current value of $p inside the loop …

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your $str variable each loop.

```
$p = 1;

while ( $p < 10 ) {
    $str = "Count {$p}";
    echo  $str . PHP_EOL;
    $p++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you cant initiate **$str** inside your loop you can simply perform some concatenation to serve your purpose-

```
$p   = 1;
$str = "Count " ;
while ( $p < 10 ) {
    echo  $str . $p . PHP_EOL;
    $p++;
}
```